# Tensorflow Tensorboard (Ngrok) on Google Colab

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, google-colaboratory, tensorboard, ngrok

I am trying to make a custom Object Detection Model on Google Colab. I am facing problem to launch Tensorboard. Just before start the Training I ran the below commands for Ngrok.

```
!wget https://bin.equinox.io/c/4VmDzA7iaHb/ngrok-stable-linux-amd64.zip
!unzip ngrok-stable-linux-amd64.zip

LOG_DIR = '/tmp/log'
get_ipython().system_raw(
    'tensorboard --logdir {} --host 0.0.0.0 --port 6006 &'
    .format(LOG_DIR)
)

get_ipython().system_raw('./ngrok http 6006 &')

!curl -s http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels | python3 -c \
    "import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)['tunnels'][0]['public_url'])"
```

And got output with URL like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jePO.png).

Then I started training and after that I went to the URL. But no data found there. Can anyone advise where I am making mistake ?

Also one more ques ... I found to stop the Training I need to use `Ctrl+C`. But how to send `Ctrl+C` on Colab Notebook?

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Answer (score 4):

Using Ngrok to get a tunnel to a TensorBoard instance in Colab used to
be a fairly common practice, but it’s not needed anymore: TensorBoard
has built-in support for notebook environments, including Colab and
Jupyter. After loading the `tensorboard` notebook extension, you can
just start your command line with `%tensorboard`, and it should just
work:

```py
%load_ext tensorboard  # only needed once (e.g., at top of notebook)

%tensorboard --logdir logs
```

[image: Screenshot of TensorBoard running in Colab]

You also don’t need to set the host and port (though you can; it should
still work as long as the host resolves), and you don’t need to run in
the background. The TensorBoard instance shown in the notebook will
continue to refresh live as you write more training data from your Colab
notebook.

For more details, you can take a look at the [docs for “Using
TensorBoard in Notebooks”](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/tensorboard_in_notebooks).

(Disclosure: I work on TensorBoard and implemented this functionality.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for suggestion. Any advise on how to send "Ctrl+C" on Colab Notebook to stop Training?

Comment: Clicking [the “stop” button directly to the left of the cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7DHA.png) sends the Ctrl-C signal (`KeyboardInterrupt` exception). You can also select the menu item *Runtime* → *Interrupt execution*.

Comment: Tensorboard on Colab used to support embedding projector. But now it isn't supported. Can you support it again? @wchargin

Comment: @KorakotChaovavanich: Please open an issue if you’re running into any problems: <https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/new/choose>